# problm in installing python modules

Tags: python, module

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 
'C:\Users\NARAYANAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NARAYANAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-3bizn71r\\cppy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NARAYANAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-3bizn71r\\cppy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\NARAYANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gkjuj9vn'
           cwd: C:\Users\NARAYANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-3bizn71r\cppy\
      Complete output (6 lines):
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
```

Comment: in which modules are you facing errors?

Comment: Please also show the actual command you are running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.